# Get interactive html/css from Adobe XD

Tags: html, css, user-experience, adobe-xd

I'm using Adobe XD from the first time, I'm working actually on an xd created by a designer to export HTML/CSS scripts to be injected in the web application (Spring boot / JSP)

I've tried with the Adobe plugin Web Export, the static HTML/CSS pages are generated but the UI elements (textfield, checkboxes, radio, buttons...) are not interactive, they are just kind of static forms (rect, svg...)

- Is there another way to export the XD to HTML pages much closer to
  the expected template ?
- Is there any required configuration to be    done on the original XD
  ?
- Do I have to rework them all and replace    them with the correct
  components ?

Am I missing something ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot export interactive UI elements from XD. Usually, designers use XD with component libraries, elements from which you can use in the final code.